# How to open different modal windows on same page

Tags: modal-dialog

I have several links on a page. I want to create a modal alert window for each link letting people know they are leaving the site. (It's a requirement for our website.) The code I am using will only allow one modal open on a page. Can you help me figure out how to get a different modals to open for each link?

Here's the javascript:

```
function overlay() {
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

The HTML:

```
<p><a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>Click here to show the overlay</a></p>
```

The HTML for the Modal:

```
<div id="overlay">
 <div>
      <p align="left">You are about to leave the website.</p>
      <p align="left"><a href="http://www.google.com"></a></p>
      <p align="left">Click here to <a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>cancel</a></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you want "different" overlays or just the same one with another link? In the latter case, it would make more sense to dynamically change the link via js...

Comment: I can use the same overlay. I just need a different link on each one.

Comment: Then just give the `<a>` tag in the overlay an id and modify its `href` with javascript. The easiest way to do that would probably be changing your `overlay` function to take the link as a parameter and modify the element accordingly. You could then use it as `overlay("link1.com")`, `overlay("link2.net")` in the onclick events for the different links.

Comment: My javascript is really bad. I've been trying to work on the code to do what you suggested and it sounds right in my head. I just can't get it to work. Can you show me an example of what I'm supposed to change.